# KNN image classifier: permission and memory errors

Tags: python, image, classification, knn

I am trying to create a KNN image classifier that distinguishes cats from dogs. However, each time I try to make a prediction I get a memory error and a permission error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

Datadir ="C:/Users/NIMROID/Music/PetImages"
typess =["Dog", "Cat"]

for types in typess:
   path =os.path.join(Datadir, types)
      for img in os.listdir(path):
          img_array =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
IMG_SIZE= 50
training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for types in typess:
        path =os.path.join(Datadir, types)
        class_num = typess.index(types)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            img_array =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            new_array =cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE ,IMG_SIZE))
            training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        create_training_data()
        import random
        random.shuffle(training_data)
        X= []
        y= []
        for features, label in training_data:
             X.append(features)
            y.append(features)

       X= np.array(X)
       y=np.array(y)
       from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
       X_train,X_test , y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.1)
       X_train=tf.keras.utils.normalize(X_train, axis=1)
       X_test= tf.keras.utils.normalize(X_test,axis=1)
       X_train= X_train.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE*IMG_SIZE)
       X_test= X_test.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE*IMG_SIZE)
       from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as kn
       from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
       knni= kn(n_neighbors =5)
       knn = MultiOutputClassifier(knni, n_jobs=-1)
       knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

> ~.conda\envs\nimrod\lib\shutil.py in _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
>        391         else:
>        392             try:
>        -->      393                 os.unlink(fullname)
>        394             except OSError:
>        395                 onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used   by another process:
>   'C:\Users\NIMROID\AppData\Local\Temp
>            \joblib_memmapping_folder_9268_8897152710   \9268-2914779649472-8c4617f562464b2e82b25e82d72afe18.pkl'
>              MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>             ~.conda\envs\nimrod\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
>               907                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
>                --> 908                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
>                909                 else:
>
> ```
>        ~\.conda\envs\nimrod\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in
> ```
>
> wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
>       553         try:
>   --> 554             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
>       555         except LokyTimeoutError:

Answer (score 1):

Im so sorry umm the

```
for features, label in training_data:
         X.append(features)
        y.append(features)
```

was wrong it was supposed to be

```
for features, label in training_data:
         X.append(features)
        y.append(label)
```

and

```
   from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as kn
   from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
   knni= kn(n_neighbors =5)
   knn = MultiOutputClassifier(knni, n_jobs=-1) #wrong
```

was supposed to be

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as kn
knn= kn(n_neighbors =5)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

and It works just fine giving me an accuracy of 59% Love you guys

Answer (score 0):

Reading your error message:

`PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used   by another process`

Could it be as simple as that ?

Comment: I left out a big chunk of the error , could there be anythingideally wrong with my code?